# Angular JS what is current scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Controller

```js
function MainController($scope, $rootScope, $location, $route) {
    $scope.EditMode = false;

    $scope.Click = function () {
        $scope.EditMode = !$scope.EditMode;
    };
}
```

HTML

```html
<button ng-if="!EditMode" ng-click="$parent.EditMode = !$parent.EditMode">Button1</button>
<button ng-if="!EditMode" ng-click="EditMode = !EditMode">Button2</button>
<button ng-if="!EditMode" ng-click="Click()">Button3</button>
```

Button1 - work

Button2 - NOT work

Button3 - Work

Why Button2 not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add the directive `ng-if` it create new scope.
The new scope have the same values from the parent scope. That why `button1` and `button3` works.

Buttons2 not work because when you do `EditMode = !EditMode` it create new variable named `EditMode` in the new scope.

You have several options to fix it. The most simple one is to replace all `ng-if` with `ng-show`

## Solution #1:

```
<button ng-show="!EditMode" ng-click="$parent.EditMode = !$parent.EditMode">Button1</button>
<button ng-show="!EditMode" ng-click="EditMode = !EditMode">Button2</button>
<button ng-show="!EditMode" ng-click="Click()">Button3</button>
```

---

### Solution #2:

Make `EditMode` as object. And keep your `ng-if` This way the new scope will not override the parent scope.

```
function MainController($scope, $rootScope, $location, $route) {
    $scope.EditMode = {value:false};

    $scope.Click = function () {
        $scope.EditMode.value = !$scope.EditMode.value;
    };
}

<button ng-if="!EditMode.value" ng-click="EditMode.value = !EditMode.value">Button1</button>
<button ng-if="!EditMode.value" ng-click="EditMode.value = !EditMode.value">Button2</button>
<button ng-if="!EditMode.value" ng-click="Click()">Button3</button>
```

---

## More info:

### Solution #1:

- [Angularjs ng-model doesn't work inside ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342917/angularjs-ng-model-doesnt-work-inside-ng-if)
- [The Difference Between Ng-show vs. Ng-if](http://appendto.com/2015/09/the-difference-between-ng-show-vs-ng-if/)

### Solution #2:

- [AngularJS $scope prototypal inheritance - primitive vs. objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881291/angularjs-scope-prototypal-inheritance-primitive-vs-objects)

Comment: Thanks! Mark as answer after 11 minutes.

Comment: Left out a more common fix which is use controllerAs

Answer (score 0):

Because an ngIf defines its own scope, which prototypically inherits from its parent scope (just like ngRepeat). So, when you change the value of a field inside an ngIf, you change it in the ngIf scope, and not in its parent scope.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes read this .. It will help you to understand the scope concept in details